# How to prove that we can't define discontinuous function on $R$?

Tags: smooth-functions, infinitesimals, synthetic-differential-geometry

I tried to do it like this:

Let for any map $g : \Delta \to R$ we have one element $b \in R$ that satisfies following:
for every $\varepsilon \in \Delta$, the equality $g(\varepsilon)=g(0)+b\varepsilon$ holds.

Let's define map $d: \Delta \to R$. Let's suppose that $d$ is defined for every $\varepsilon \in \Delta$ but $d$ is discontinuous. We get that equality $d(\varepsilon)=d(0)+b\varepsilon$ doesn't hold because there is no such element $b$ that satisfies this equality.

Now, I don't know how to conclude from this statement that $d$ isn't defined for all $\varepsilon \in \Delta$.

How to prove that we can't define discontinuous function on $R$?

Thanks.

Comment: How would you define a continuous function on Bell's $R$?

Comment: @MikhailKatz In general sense define as function whose graph does not have any breaks or holes. (e.g. $g(x)=x^2$). In Bell's book I read that "arbitrary functions from R to R behave locally like polynomials; all smooth functions have Taylor expansions".

Comment: A "graph does not have any breaks or holes" is not a mathematical definition.  One possibility would be to define continuity as Bell does, as sending infinitely close points to infinitely close points.

Comment: @MikhailKatz It's impossible to define discontinuous function on $R$. How does it prove?

Comment: Which definition of continuity are you working with?

Comment: @MikhailKatz If $a$ and $b$ in $R$ are such that $a-b$ is in $\Delta$, then $f(a)-f(b) \in \Delta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ and $b$ are in $R$ such that $a-b=\epsilon$ is in $\Delta$, then we have $f(b)=f(a) + k \epsilon$ for a suitable slope $k$, as you mentioned.  But $k\epsilon$ is necessarily in $\Delta$, as well.  Therefore the function is continuous.  One way of summarizing this is that $\Delta$ is an ideal in $R$ but this claim should be checked (there might be some subtleties because the background logic is intuitionstic; I haven't thought this through fully).

Comment: It works for smooth functions. But if we try to define discontinuous function $f(x)$ on $R$ and for $f(0)=0$, $f(\varepsilon)=1$ we have $b-a=\varepsilon$ is in $\Delta$ but $f(b)-f(a)=1$ isn't in $\Delta$

Comment: @Mike_bb, such a function is not defined on all of $R$.  You can't even define it on all of $\Delta$ because $\epsilon$ is indistinguishable from $0$.

Comment: Yes. My question is about it. (How to prove that discontinuous function can't be defined on $R$?)

Comment: Well try it and see if you can :-)

Comment: I see it on examples but is there rigorous proof ?

Comment: @Mike_bb, the rigorous proof is the one I gave in my *answer* :-)